# What makes my information get deleted from `memcached`

Tags: express, memcached, express-session

Currently i am using [memcached](https://github.com/memcached/memcached) + [connect-memcached](https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached) + [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to have the user information stored temporarily during the lifecycle.

But i found the user information got delete very fast recently which i have no idea why? It happened as following:

1. Login with a username and password, the user info should be stored for `7` days due to my `express-session` config `cookie: { maxAge: 86400000 * 7 }`
2. After login, just leave the mouse and keyboard for a while(may be 1 minute)
3. Try click something on the webpage that requires user info
4. While digging the node code, i do have the sessionId cause it was set in cookie, and `memcached` just returned nothing with the `key` which almost kill me.

I didn't find any document about this behavior, can someone help?

I'd like to know why the information get deleted even it's not expired?

I've given `2000` to `-m` option for `memcached` even i could't find any documentation described it(i thought it should be a memory usage).